# Strcat result having data from last strcat call

Tags: c, file, strcat

I'm saving data in two different file and using strcat to concatenate these data.
Strangely, the result of my last strcat call get concat to the two string I want to concat now.
It might be a bit blurry so here is the code :

```
...
strcat(logline,"\n");
if(logging){
    if(writeInFile(logfile,"a",logline))
         printf("    Connection logged.");
    else
         printf("    Connection couldn't be logged.");        
}

if(saving){
    char* loc = (char*) malloc(BUFSIZ);
    strcat(loc,client_ip);
    strcat(loc,"-");
    strcat(loc,server_ip);
    strcat(loc,".txt");

    if(writeInFile(loc,"a",request)){
          printf("    Connection saved.");
    }
    else{
          printf("ERROR: cannot create/open savefile %s\n",loc);
          printf("Saving set to FALSE.");
          saving = false;
    }
}
```

```
bool writeInFile(char* fileName, char* openingParam, char* content){
    if(strcmp(openingParam,"a") == 0 || strcmp(openingParam,"w") == 0){
        FILE* fptr = NULL;
        fptr = fopen(fileName,openingParam);
        if ( fptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("ERROR: cannot create/open logfile %s\n",fileName);
            return false;
        }
        fprintf(fptr,"%s",content);
        fclose(fptr);
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

What's happening is that the content of logline is put at the start of loc.
So a file with a hell long name is created.

EDIT :: The file is supposed to be named like 192.168.1.36-192.168.1.36.txt

but is instead named like

```
|--> timestamp = Sat Jan  2 20:09:24 2021
|--> remote    = 192.168.1.36
|--> local     = 192.168.1.36
|--> request   = [timeout]
|--> END
192.168.1.36-192.168.1.36.txt
```

```
|--> timestamp = Sat Jan  2 20:09:24 2021
|--> remote    = 192.168.1.36
|--> local     = 192.168.1.36
|--> request   = [timeout]
|--> END
```

Being the value of logline obtained via strcat.

Comment: `strcat(loc,client_ip);` invokes *undefined behavior*  since `loc` is filled with uninitialized data and `strcat` looks for a null-terminator

Comment: That was so stupid, thanks for the fast answer !  Had seen people having problem with uninitialized string but since I didn't found any occurrence of my problem I thought it wasn't that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) function requires that the destination string really is a proper null-terminated string. Otherwise it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The buffer you allocate with `malloc` is not initialized in any way. It's definitely not a null-terminated string.

You have four possible solutions:

1. Use `strcpy` instead of `strcat` for the first call:

   ```
   strcpy(loc,client_ip);
   ```
2. Initialize the buffer, for example like this:

   ```
   loc[0] = '\0';  // Terminate the buffer, making it an "empty" string
   strcat(loc,client_ip);
   ```
3. Call `calloc` instead of `malloc`, as that will zero the allocated memory, which is the same as setting it all to the string null-terminator:

   ```
   char* loc = calloc(BUFSIZ, 1);
   ```
4. Use `snprintf` to "print" the string into the uninitialized buffer:

   ```
   snprintf(loc, BUFSIZ, "%s-%s.txt", client_ip, server_ip);
   ```

Personally I recommend method 4, using `snprintf`.

---

There's also another problem with your code: A memory leak because you don't pass the memory you allocated to `free`.

Either call `free(loc)` before `loc` goes out of scope; Or make`loc` an array instead:

```
char loc[BUFSIZ];
```

Making `loc` an array instead also means you can easily initialize it:

```
char loc[BUFSIZ] = { '\0' };
```

Answer (score 0):

Loc is uninitialized, strcat behavior with uninit var is undefined, that was the problem.
Replacing the first occurrence of strcat with strcpy solved it !

```
if(saving){
    char* loc = (char*) malloc(BUFSIZ);
    strcpy(loc,client_ip);
    strcat(loc,"-");
    strcat(loc,server_ip);
    strcat(loc,".txt");

    if(writeInFile(loc,"a",request)){
          printf("    Connection saved.");
    }
    else{
          printf("ERROR: cannot create/open savefile %s\n",loc);
          printf("Saving set to FALSE.");
          saving = false;
    }
}
```